# jQuery mobile localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I am trying to display the `localStorage` information on another area of my app. I am not able to grab the information entered into my `localstorage textarea`.

This is the HTML:

```html
<div class="main-nav" id="page" data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-add-back-btn="true">
  <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel">
    <h2 style="color:green; text-align: center;">Favorite Items</h2>
    <ul data-role="content" data-theme="c">
      <p>Enter your favorite items.</p>
      <textarea class="localstorage" id="storage" placeholder="Information here will be stored." autofocus></textarea>
      <button class="clear">Clear localStorage</button>
      <button class="empty">Empty localStorage</button>
    </ul>
    <p>You can close this panel by clicking outside of it, pressing the Esc key, or by swiping.</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="page" id="favorites" data-theme="a" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-add-back-btn="true">
      <h1>Your favorites are listed here</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <p>Click the button below to display your entry.</p>
      <!-- Javascript button to capture and display the input -->
      <button onclick="getInfo()">List Favorites</button>
      <p id="data"></p>
      </head>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" id="footer9">
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the JavaScript:

```js
var val = document.getElementById("storage").value;
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = val;

(function() {
  var rasm = document.querySelector('.localstorage');

  function supportsLocalStorage() {
    return typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined';
  }

  if (!supportsLocalStorage()) {
    rasm.value = 'Your browser does not support localStorage.';
  } else {
    try {
      setInterval(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('autosave', rasm.value);
      }, 1000);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
        alert('Quota exceeded!');
      }
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem('autosave')) {
      rasm.value = localStorage.getItem('autosave');
    }

    document.querySelector('.clear').onclick = function() {
      rasm.value = '';
      localStorage.removeItem('autosave');
    };

    document.querySelector('.empty').onclick = function() {
      rasm.value = '';
      localStorage.clear();
    };
  }
})();
```

For some reason, The information entered just does not show up in the paragraph section.

It would also be great if I could click on the button and then have the information show, but it would be enough to just have the information show in the paragraph section.

Comment: Have you been able to manually read and write this information to the localstorage?

Comment: To get the value of a textarea, you need to use `innerHTML` instead of `value`.

Comment: Yes, the local storage works fine. It is the manner in which I am trying to access the textarea that is not showing up. I tried replacing value with innerHTML and innerText, yet it did not work.

Comment: And where's the getInfo() function defined? I am getting a console error here on on <button onclick="getInfo()">List Favorites</button>

Comment: Yea, that function is something extra I was working on. It is supposed to grab the localstorage data and display it when the user clicks on it. Though I have not been able to implement it. It should however, not block the paragraph from displaying.

Comment: got it, let me post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple, just a matter of reorganizing your function.

Try to play a bit with the console.log() to understand what is the order of execution of your function, because right now the way it is, it is setting the paragraph with an empty value.

Move the lines below to the end of your function:

```
var val = document.getElementById("storage").value;
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = val;
```

This way it does not run before you were even able to get the values you need to write in there.

You have to reload the page to be able to see what's changed in the text area (and what is saved to localstorage) because in your current implementation there's no other way to re-render the page without doing that.

Good luck.

Comment: Was able to add it to a function for button click. Thanks! You're great!

Comment: Glad it worked, thanks. Would you up vote my answer?

Comment: Done. Thank you for everything.